# Mac Charger clicks once when plugging in, but there are no sparks

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

I have noticed that, when I plug in My MagSafe Charger Replacement(It's a 'T' model), It makes a single *CLICK* sound, but I see no sparks, and It only *CLICKS* sometimes, Is there something wrong I am doing? I JUST got this charger.

Comment: if you get sparks when connecting **ANY** power adapter to **ANY** computer there is something very very wrong with the computer and/or the power adapter.

Comment: I am getting no sparks

Comment: The way it was worded sounded to me as if you *expected sparks.* A long time ago someone joked that "computers and other electronics run on smoke. If you let the smoke out they stop working." Sparks are often the precursor to smoke.